# Is there a way to draw the Y AxisLabels vertically in chart4j?

Tags: java, charts, charts4j

Is there a way to draw the Y [`AxisLabels`](http://charts4j.googlecode.com/svn/tags/v1.2/doc/com/googlecode/charts4j/AxisLabels.html) vertically in [`chart4j`](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/) (make the text labels sideways to condense space)? I could not find a way online, so I am guessing is probably does not exist, but does anyone know?

Comment: I wrote charts4j. I do not have a clear understanding of what you are trying to do. Have you followed the examples at charts4j.googlecode.com? Alternatively, please supply an example of what you want.